# AWS:Could I use spot instance instead of shutting down/starting up on-demand instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a linux machine (m3.large) configured to do database processing maybe 4 consecutive days a month, and I have an 120 Gb volume that has my data, applications ectera stored. Then for the rest of the time I stop the instance, so I only pay for the machine for 4 days a month, I pay for the 120gb volume 24 hours a day but the cost of this is low compared with running the machine.

Because I only use the machine for a few days a month reserved instance would be no good for me, but I wonder if I could use Spot instance. It wouldnt matter to me if the machine was not exactly the same as m3.large as long as it was approximate.

What I was concerned about was having to setup the machine every time (i.e install my code, database ectera) , but if I have my own volume could I just link that to the new machine or is it tied to the particular instance I currently have running. i.e if i terminate (rather than just stopping ) my current instance will the volume also be deleted or can I reuse with another (spot) instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - spot instances will only turn on when the price matches your bid price.  if you don't care when the instanceis up, spot is good, however if there is ever going to be a time where you need the instance it might not spawn up if the price is not right.

check this out: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html

You can have your files on an EBS and mount it every time the instance starts: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

Comment: I don't need it at specific time, just the right day, and actually even the day after would be okay. So can you give me some idea of how likley/unlikely there will be a spot instance available in this time frame ?

Comment: Nope, spot is no good for you if that's the case.  There is no guarantee it will even run on the day - and even if it did, it can be turned off any time the spot price exceeds the bid price.  The more you bid, the more likely it is to spawn the instance however even then its not a guarantee.

Comment: okay thanks I will stick with on-demand instance. Since I am only using for a few days anyway the cost is not that much.